# Office 2010 Look and Feel?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am getting started on a WPF app whose UI will be modeled rather loosely on Outlook. I would like to emulate the Blue color scheme in the Outlook 2010 beta. Has anyone seen any tutorials or recipes that describe how to style WPF buttons so that they look like Outlook 2010's Task buttons? Those are the ones in the lower-left corner of the Outlook 2010 main window. Thanks

Comment: Could you please share a screenshot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a very basic template for an Outlook 2010 task button, which was created in Expression Blend. I separated the template as a window resource. But notice that the image and text are hard-coded into the markup. To use this template, you will need to either incorporate it into each button you declare, as a separate control template for that button, or you will need to create a custom control with appropriate properties to which you can bind.

Note also that I haven't created triggers. To emulate an Outlook 2010 button, the default state should be borderless--the border and glass effects should appear for a mouse-over, a mouse-press, and so on. Nonetheless, the template shows how to get the Outlook 2010 look.

You can check out the button by creating a new WPF project and replacing the Window1 markup with the markup below.

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="Outlook_2010_Task_Button.MainWindow"
    x:Name="Window"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="640" Height="480" Background="#FFB7C9E0">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="TaskButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
            <Border x:Name="OuterBorder" Width="150" Height="28" BorderBrush="#FF59697F" BorderThickness="0.75" Background="#FFB0C8E2" Opacity="0.85" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                <Border.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="3" Opacity="0.1"/>
                </Border.Effect>
                <Border x:Name="InnerBorder" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="0.75" Background="{x:Null}" Opacity="0.75" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border x:Name="Glow" Margin="0.999,0,-0.999,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <RadialGradientBrush Center="0.494,0.98" GradientOrigin="0.494,0.98" RadiusX="0.56" RadiusY="1.018">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#CCFFFFFF"/>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="1"/>
                                </RadialGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="Shine" Margin="0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#87FFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0.319"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>
                        </Border>
                        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,0,0,0" Source="calendar.png"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Calendar" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="9,0,0,0" Foreground="#FF001955" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <RadioButton HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="RadioButton" Template="{DynamicResource TaskButtonTemplate}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2):

[Here's a ready-made paid product solution](http://www.devcomponents.com/blog/?p=581) that might help... Does the solution need to be free/open source? This one has a free trial.

Comment: Thanks, but I avoid those products in WPF. For me, it's actually easier to whip up something in Expression Blend, rather than adding another dependency to my app.

Comment: $264 for developer isn't too much to spend on a pretty funcational toolbar. I'm sure that you can't build a tool bar in a couple of hours that looks or acts as well as this one would.

Comment: Not to start a flame war, Chris, but I probably can. It really comes down to a matter of personal preference. I try to minimize dependencies on third party controls, and I'm pretty good with Blend. I do recognize, however, that others may feel differently and might prefer to use a third-party control.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using NavigationPane (CodePlex) which will provide much more features than just Outlook 2010 Task buttons styles:

- http://navigationpane.codeplex.com/

Also for Ribbon look and feel I recommend using Fluent:

- http://fluent.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

You should try expression blend 3 (there is a free trial). You can create a style very easily by editing the button template. The button looks to me like it just has a gradient, an icon, a border and text.

Comment: That's actually what I am doing; I use Blend to do my UIs. I had hoped to find a recipe to set the buttons, so that I could avoid playing around in Blend to get it right.

Comment: The button is actually a little more complicated than that, but it was pretty easy to duplicate in Blend. It has an outer and inner borders, a 'shine' effect, and a 'glow' effect. Structurally, it is very similar to a Vista glass button. I have posted the markup above. There is a very good tutorial on this sort of button at http://blogs.msdn.com/mgrayson/archive/2007/02/16/creating-a-glass-button-the-complete-tutorial.aspx.